# Bind data from database and rotate / transpose data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to retrieve data from SQL database and bind to control(Datagridview / Datalist). Make a table format output and it will shows Rows as column and column as rows.

I have one table: tbl_CustData with two fields such as FixedDepDate(datetime datatype) and another is **Month_year (nvarchar datatype)**. The values are as follows:

```
 FixedDepDate            |  Month_year   |
-------------------------+---------------+
2018-07-03 00:00:00.000  | March - 18    |  
2018-08-23 00:00:00.000  | August - 2018 | 
2018-08-29 00:00:00.000  | August - 2018 |
2018-07-04 00:00:00.000  | July - 2018   |
2018-07-10 00:00:00.000  | July - 2018   |
2018-07-25 00:00:00.000  | July - 2018   |
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
March - 18    | 03
July - 18     | 04 | 10 | 25
August - 18   | 23 | 29
```

I already tried following methods but not getting output which is I am expecting.

1. Used Datalist/Gridview control and tried to bind data
2. Used PIVOTE operator but not getting output.

Also please give some idea which control is suitable to bind the data and show on my webpage or else any technique to resolve this problem.
Note: I am not using any events to show my output. Want to display my output directly on my page after run the project.

Comment: You didn't specify your backend. This might be  solved in backend if it is one of those that make it simple for things like this or frontend.

Comment: I am using SQL Server as a backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clearly explain what you want from the start.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    [FixedDepDate] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #temp
(
    [FixedDepDate]
)
VALUES
('2018-03-07 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-08-23 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-08-29 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-04 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-10 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-25 00:00:00.000');

WITH source AS
(
SELECT 
     YEAR(FixedDepDate) AS y,
     MONTH(FixedDepDate) AS m, 
     DATENAME(MONTH, FixedDepDate) + ' - ' + 
     DATENAME(YEAR, FixedDepDate) AS YearMonth,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY YEAR(FixedDepDate) * 10000 + 
                    MONTH(FixedDepDate)
        ORDER BY DAY(FixedDepDate)) AS nDay,
     RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(FixedDepDate))), 2) AS cDay
FROM #temp
)
SELECT YearMonth, [1], [2], [3]
       FROM source
       PIVOT ( max(cDay) 
       FOR [nDay] IN ( [1], [2], [3] )
       ) pvt
ORDER BY y,m;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

EDIT:

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Test;Trusted_connection=yes"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var columns = Convert.ToInt32(new SqlCommand(@"SELECT MAX(cnt)
                                    FROM
                                    (
                                        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                                        FROM MyDates
                                        GROUP BY YEAR(FixedDepDate),
                                                 MONTH(FixedDepDate)
                                    ) tmp;", con)
                        .ExecuteScalar());

        var collist = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, columns).Select(e => $"[{e}]"));
        var pivot = $@"WITH source AS
(
SELECT 
     YEAR(FixedDepDate) AS y,
     MONTH(FixedDepDate) AS m, 
     DATENAME(MONTH, FixedDepDate) + ' - ' + 
     DATENAME(YEAR, FixedDepDate) AS YearMonth,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY YEAR(FixedDepDate) * 10000 + 
                    MONTH(FixedDepDate)
        ORDER BY DAY(FixedDepDate)) AS nDay,
     RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(FixedDepDate))), 2) AS cDay
FROM Mydates
)
SELECT YearMonth, {collist}
       FROM source
       PIVOT ( max(cDay) 
       FOR [nDay] IN ( {collist} )
       ) pvt
ORDER BY y,m;
";

        tbl.Load( new SqlCommand(pivot,con).ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }


    var f = new Form();
    var dgv = new DataGridView {Dock=DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=tbl};
    f.Controls.Add(dgv);
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yeess..!!! this is expected result man. Only the problem is that , you take [1],[2],[3] columns  in for [nDay] IN() statement as manually as per the date. Now I want  to create columns dynamically. For ex : If August has 3 dates then, it should display 3 dates as per same your query. It should display the columns as per the dates(cDay).

Comment: @PankajSonawane, it is easy to get the max day count in C# and create that "[1],[2],[3]" part dynamically.

Comment: I understood, but can you make changes in your query for my expected output? pleaseeeeee...

Comment: @PankajSonawane, edited for C# code. Next time please do such easy stuff yourself and don't call others to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by year, month and then aggregate days for that period. ie:

```
var result = from d in db.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
             group d by d.FixedDepDate.ToString("MMMM-yyyy")
             into g
             select new
             {
                 Period = g.Key,
                 Days = string.Join(" | ", g.Select(x => x.FixedDepDate.Day))
             };
```

With your sample data (corrected) the output is:

```
Period       Days

March-2018   7 
August-2018  23 | 29 
July-2018    4 | 10 | 25
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need it in T-SQL when you are going to bind to a DataGridView. Anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    [FixedDepDate] DATETIME );

INSERT INTO #temp
(
    [FixedDepDate]
)
VALUES
('2018-03-07 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-08-23 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-08-29 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-04 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-10 00:00:00.000'),
('2018-07-25 00:00:00.000');



SELECT ym.YearMonth,
       (
           SELECT RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(FixedDepDate))), 2) + ' | '
           FROM #temp t
           WHERE YEAR(t.FixedDepDate) = ym.y
                 AND MONTH(t.FixedDepDate) = ym.m
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS [Days]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           DATENAME(MONTH, FixedDepDate) + ' - ' + DATENAME(YEAR, FixedDepDate) AS YearMonth,
           YEAR(FixedDepDate) AS y,
           MONTH(FixedDepDate) AS m
    FROM #temp
) AS [ym]
ORDER BY y,
         m;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: This is right. But I want to display days of month in separated column. Means as per your query the 'days' displayed in single column. If month have 3 days then it will display with 3 different columns for each month i.e April - 2018 with 3 dates in 3 different column.